# Is every probability mass function $f_X$ of a random variable $X$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $X_*P$ with respect to the counting measure?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable (meaning $\text{im}(X)$ is countable) from a probability triple $(A,\mathcal{A},P)$ to a measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Measure_theoretic_formulation) (bold is mine):

> The probability density function $f$ of $X$ with respect to the counting measure, **if it exists,** is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of the pushforward measure of $X$ (with respect to the counting measure), so $f=dX_{*}P/d\mu$ and $f$ is a function from $\mathcal{B}$ to the non-negative reals. As a consequence, for any $b\in B$ we have
> $$P(X=b) = P(X^{-1}(b)) = X_*P(b) = \int_bf\text{d}\mu = f(b).$$

The phrase in bold thus seems to imply that there is a discrete random variable such that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\text{d}X_*P/\text{d}\mu$ does not exist (and thus cannot equal $f_X$), but that seems impossible to me, as we always have $X_*P<<\mu$ since the counting measure only outputs zero on the empty set, meaning we can always find a function $f$ equal to $\text{d}X_*P/\text{d}\mu$ by the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Is every probability mass function $f_X$ of a random variable $X$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $X_*P$ with respect to the counting measure?

Comment: There seem to be two different questions, one about discrete distributions and one about general distributions. Please clarify.

Comment: All random variables in the post are discrete. Does that clarify what my doubt is?

Comment: In that case, their distributions do actually have Radon-Nikodym derivatives with respect to counting measure.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I see, and do such derivatives exist by the argument I wrote?

Comment: Almost. Counting measure on an uncountable set is not $\sigma$-finite (or satisfies even an appropriate weaker condition), so you cannot directly apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem. However, you can always restrict counting measure to the relevant countable set. This gives you a Radon-Nikodym derivative that you can extend to the whole space by setting values outside the image to zero.